# Async await - does await block other code from running?

Tags: javascript, async-await

In javascript, does await block code? For example, let's say we have the below code:

```
async function queryDB() {
    const addUser = await promisePool.execute("INSERT INTO Users (User) VALUES ('username')")
    const selectUser = await promisePool.execute("SELECT User FROM Users") 
}
```

**Will "selectUser" wait to run until addUser is finished so that we can select the user that is added?**

Also, let's say that we add some code between the awaits that is not a promise, something like this:

```
    async function queryDB() {
        const addUser = await promisePool.execute("INSERT INTO Users (User) VALUES ('username')")

setTimeout(() => console.log('Do something that takes 3 seconds'), 3000);

        const selectUser = await promisePool.execute("SELECT User FROM Users") 
    }
```

**Will "selectUser" wait for addUser but not the setTimeout? If so, how would you write the above code to make addUser run first, then setTimeout and then selectUser?**

I would also like to add that I have been studying and reading on both stackoverflow and other resources, but I need some clarification.

Comment: You could move the code inside the setTimeout function or you can create a new function that returns a promise and move the setTimeout inside it, and then use await

Comment: It waits for the `await <promise>` inside of the function that you called `await` in, but it doesn't block the whole process -- other javascript that you've written may be running while you're waiting for your promises.

Comment: @TKoL ok, so it blocks all code in the same async function, correct?

Comment: I wouldn't use the term `block` because of the confusion that it's blocking the rest of the process, as that's what `blocking` usually means, but effectively yes, it blocks inside the function, but it doesn't block outside the function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Will "selectUser" wait to run until addUser is finished so that we can
> select the user that is added?

From [`MDN Docs - await:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause until a
> Promise is settled (that is, fulfilled or rejected), and to resume
> execution of the async function after fulfillment. When resumed, the
> value of the await expression is that of the fulfilled Promise.

Execution of `queryDB` function will be paused while it waits for the first promise to settle. Second line of code will only execute after first one has completed successfully.

> Will "selectUser" wait for addUser but not the setTimeout?

Yes, that is correct.

> If so, how would you write the above code to make addUser run first, then
> setTimeout and then selectUser?

You could wrap `setTimeout` in a function that returns a promise and then await that promise to make sure last line executes after first two have completed.

Following is an example of a wrapper function that wraps `setTimeout`

```
function waitForTimeout(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     setTimeout(() => { 
        console.log("Hello World");
        resolve();
     }, seconds * 1000);        
  });
}
```

Once you have a wrapper function, you can `await` it as shown below:

```
async function queryDB() {
    const addUser = await promisePool.execute(
        "INSERT INTO Users (User) VALUES ('username')"
    );

    await waitForTimeout(3);    // wait for 3 seconds

    const selectUser = await promisePool.execute("SELECT User FROM Users") 
}
```

Comment: Good example of Promisifying a function

Answer (score 6):

Important note: **blocks** is probably a bad word here. A better word is it **waits**. Even better would be probably to just say that operations that are done using `await` syntax are guaranteed to be executed sequentially.

**The Big Picture**

The main reason for using asynchronous code in Node is that **we don't block the whole app** while we wait for some asynchronous operation like a database request, a network request, a file operation etc. - we only block this particular execution context.

Even though Node.js only uses one thread for executing user code, but I/O operations are asynchronous and they're **non-blocking**.

So imagine you have an endpoint with the code that you presented above, that is linked to some button "Add user" on the front end.

- Bill presses the button, you start handling the request, start waiting for `addUser` operation
- At this point John also presses same button. Your code will still be executed and will also start to wait until `addUser` finishes.
- Let's say that `Users` table has gotten into a deadlock and any db operations with it will be super slow, and we have a third user, Jane, who is just browsing your site but she doesn't need to sign in/sign up, so she doesn't touch `Users` table. What happens? Jane is totally fine, her requests will go through without any issues.

**How to await setTimeout**

`setTimeout` is coming from "previous era" so it uses callback instead of async/await syntax. But it is always possible to convert callback style to async/await, if you need it.

```js
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
await delay(5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, await only blocks the code(s) that's after the await statement in the current async function, not the whole thread. Once the await has been resolved the rest of the code gets executed. In your example, since you have 2 await statements, the second one won't run until the first one has finished, because the first one blocks the function that both await statements are inside of. For the second example, since `setTimeout()` doesn't return a promise and you aren't awaiting it either, the function will treat it as a 'synchronous' operation. That is, it will throw the `setTimeout()` callback into the call stack till the next event loop and continue executing the next line which is another await statement that will block the function again until it is resolved.

In order to execute all three lines one by one, you'll have to put the `setTimeout()` into a promise and await it so that JS treats it as an asynchronous operation and 'waits' for it to finish before moving on to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

**Will "selectUser" wait to run until addUser is finished so that we can select the user that is added?**

Yes.

**Will "selectUser" wait for addUser but not the setTimeout? If so, how would you write the above code to make addUser run first, then setTimeout and then selectUser?**

"selectUser" will be executed after "addUser", but not the setTimeout callback. If you want to run "selectUser" after setTimeout, you can add it inside the setTimeout callback function. So it should look like:

```js
 async function queryDB() {
  const addUser = await promisePool.execute("INSERT INTO Users (User) VALUES ('username')")

  setTimeout(async () => {
    const selectUser = await promisePool.execute("SELECT User FROM Users");
  }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, it blocks. The purpose of await is, to make sure you have the result available in the next line. So if you needed the value of addUser to make the next query, you would have it.

It was introduced so you don't have to write then() at the end of the first line and put the second call into a callback, which makes the code hard to read.

Comment: `blocks` is the wrong word though, isn't it? It `blocks` that single function, but it's not `blocking` the rest of the process - other code can run while it's waiting for the bit you're awaiting.

Comment: Thats right. Since js has no real notion of a thread or process, and always runs in a single process, the ability to block that one process would be scary because everyone could just stop the execution of js altogether. So yeah, the correct wording would be it halts further execution in the current code branch. The event loop (and therefore timers) would still be running though.

Comment: The answer should really incorporate these comments as they may mean more than the answer itself. I hope people will read them.

Answer (score 0):

*addUser* is executed and as it returns a Promise, it is added to MicroTask Queue.

Then EventLoop checks if JS Call Stack is empty/nothing to execute. Then it takes the *addUser* from MicroTask Queue and finally settled.

While all this is happening, the *queryDB* is blocked since async await is used.

Then JS executes the *setTimeout*, and attaches the callback to the timer(Browser Web APIs).

Then JS moves to *selectUser* and since it returns a promise, it is added to MicroTask Queue.

EventLoop again checks if JS Call Stack is empty or/nothing to execute. Then it takes the *selectUser* from MicroTask Queue, even though there is a timer already expired and the callback function of *setTimeout* is in the callback Queue. Because the priority of MicroTask Queue > Call back Queue.

To avoid this, we need to use Promisification in JS. Turning *setTimeout* to wrap it with Promise. So that it is added to MicroTask Queue before *selectUser* gets added.

Hope it helps!