# How to mock a delay in my api call function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

I have a function to update an user with an api post request. The backend is not done yet. The function will thus always return an error. In order to test the loading and error states, I would like to temporarily add a fake delay before returning the result. How to do so? Here is the function:

```js
const updateProfile = async (form) => {
  try {
    const res = await api.post("/update-profile", form);
    return res;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("error.unknown");
  }
};
```

Writing this didn't work:

```js
const updateProfile = async (form) => {
  try {
    let fakeCallDone = false
    setTimeout(()=> fakeCallDone = true, 2000)
    const res = await api.post("/update-profile", form);
    fakeCallDone && res;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("error.unknown");
  }
};
```

Comment: Try to add `await` before setTimeout ;) But the best, correct way would be to wrap the whole function in a Promise with setTimeout inside and then call the function.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65478269/async-await-does-await-block-other-code-from-running/65478322#65478322

Comment: const updateProfile = async (form) => {
  try {
    let fakeCallDone = false;
    setTimeout(function(){fakeCallDone = true;}, 2000);
    const res = await api.post("/update-profile", form);
    fakeCallDone && res;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("error.unknown");
  }
};

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a simple sleep function.

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(
  resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

And then use like

```
 await sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is here:

```
setTimeout(()=> fakeCallDone = true, 2000)
```

It will move on to `Web API` then continue to execute the next line codes.

**[Solution]**

```
const updateProfile = async (form) => {
  try {
   var res = api.post("/update-profile", form); // this async code will move on `web api`. When it's done will move on to queue.
   await delay(2000); // You mock a delay here
   return await res; // Resolve value from `res` promise. 
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("error.unknown");
  }
};
```

***delay()*** method look like this:

```
const delay= ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Note: you should get more details about `event loop` to know

1. How js works: `call stack, web API, queue, event loop`
2. Async programming in Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You can return a new promise in the meantime (Until the backend is ready):

```js
const updateProfile = async () => {
  try {
    // const res = await api.post("/update-profile", form);
    // return res;
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
     setTimeout(() => res('response'), 2000)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("error.unknown");
  }
};

updateProfile().then(console.log)
```