# Why doesn't 'await' wait for subsequent code execution?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm currently learning asynchronous operations in JavaScript, and my code is as follows:

```js
async function cout_after10(num) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(num)
    }, 10)
};

async function cout_after0(num) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(num)
    }, 0)
};

// main function 
(async function () {
    async function test() {
        await console.log(1)
        console.log(3)
        setTimeout(() => console.log(7), 5)
        console.log(4)
    }
    test()
    console.log(2)
    await cout_after10(8)
    await cout_after0(6)
    console.log(5)
})();
```

**The actual output is printed in ascending order of numbers.** But I expected the output to be:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6
```

The last three digits differ from my expectations.My understanding is that the execution sequence should be:

1. Synchronously execute `test()`, enter the scope of `test`, print 1, and put the subsequent code into the microtask queue.
2. Print 2.
3. Execute `cout_after10(8)`. Because it's an asynchronous function, it is placed in the macro task queue. The first `await` in `cout_after10(8)` blocks subsequent code until it completes and puts the subsequent code into the microtask queue.
4. Synchronous code has been executed, now fetch the function from the microtask queue. Print 3, place `setTimeout(() => console.log(7), 5)` into the macro task queue, print 4.
5. Now, start executing the second part in the microtask queue, which is the part after `await cout_after10(8)`. `cout_after0(6)` is placed in the macro task queue, and then put its subsequent code `console.log(5)` into the microtask queue.
6. Now, only `console.log(5)` is left in the microtask queue, print 5.

**My thinking so far seems correct, but the following steps are completely different from what I expected.**

7. My understanding is that it will enter the macro task queue now and execute in the order of insertion:

   ```js
   setTimeout(() => console.log(7), 5);
   cout_after10(8);
   cout_after0(6);
   ```

   In theory, it should print 7, 8, 6. However, it doesn't. Instead, it prints 6,7,8, in the order of whoever finishes first, corresponding to their delays: 0, 5, 10.

I have read some relevant materials about `await`, such as this one: [does await block other code from running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65478269/async-await-does-await-block-other-code-from-running). According to this, the code should execute in the order of `await`:

```js
await cout_after10(8);
await cout_after0(6);
```

And print 8 and 6. But why is it behaving differently now? It seems like `await` is not working as expected.

---

Based on the replies, **I modified my code by changing the return value to a Promise,** which is as follows. It does work

```js
async function cout_after10(num) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(num)
            resolve(0)
        }, 10)
    })
};

async function cout_after0(num) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(num)
            resolve(0)
        }, 0)
    })
};

// main function 
(async function () {
    async function test() {
        await console.log(1)
        console.log(3)
        setTimeout(() => console.log(7), 5)
        console.log(4)
    }
    test()
    console.log(2)
    await cout_after10(8)
    await cout_after0(6)
    console.log(5)
})();
```

Comment: `async/await` uses `Promises`, `timeouts` do not make a function `async`, they just delay the execution of _another_ function until later. The wrapping function immediately returns a value. An async function should have a return signature of `Promise<value>` instead of just `value`

Comment: `setTimeout` itself is not a promise, so `awaiting` it does nothing. You should instead make a promise which is resolved at the end of the timeout: `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));`

Comment: Regarding your edited code, you need to `resolve()` your promise in the `setTimeout()` callback.

Comment: You also have an await in front of a console.log, which returns void (not a Promise).

Comment: @StevenLacks Thank you for pointing that out. In fact, the presence of that code was because I wanted to see how `await` behaves when encountering `non-Promise` objects before. I initially thought that the reaction of `await` to the default `Promise` object returned by `async` might be different from that scenario.